# JQuery плавный скролл страницы (НЕ ЯКОРЯ)

Tags: jquery, прокрутка, animate, mousewheel

Как можно реализовать на чистом JQuery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно и без JS

```
body {
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
```

https://caniuse.com/#search=scroll-behavior

Comment: Вау, не знал, круто=)